# How do you find criteria of this linear transformation $T(x,y,z)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

.

Question
Let $T \in L(\mathbb{R}^3,P_{2})$ such that:
$$T(1,0,0)=3x^2+x+2$$
$$T(0,1,0)=-x+1$$
$$T(0,0,1)=1$$
Determine criteria of T.

I tried the following: 
For $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3$ so, 
$T(x,y,z)=T(x(1,0,0)+y(0,1,0)+z(0,0,1))=3x^2+x+2-x+1+1$

Is it correct?. 
Context: Linear Algebra.

What do I need to complete the requested in the question?. Suggestions?.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "criteria of $T$"?

Comment: It's difficult to translate it. I can provide you an example, it is similar to requiered in my question.

Comment: Given $T(1,0,0)=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 0 & -2 \end{pmatrix} $  $T(0,1,0)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 \\ 2 & -1\end{pmatrix} $  $T(0,0,1)=\begin{pmatrix} 3 & -4 \\ 4 & 2 \end{pmatrix} $ so, find the criteria.

Comment: The right answer is:  $T(x,y,z)=\begin{pmatrix} 2x+2y+3z & x+3y-4z \\ 2y+4z & -2x-y+2z \end{pmatrix} $  this is the criteria. I need to do it like this. But my doubt is related to the polynomial. Which is the difference between matrix and polynomial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea is good, check this:
\begin{align}
T(u,v,w) &= uT(1,0,0) + vT(0,1,0) + wT(0,0,1) \\
&= u(3x^2+x+2) + v(-x+1) + w1 \\
&= (3u)x^2 + (u-v)x + (u+v+w).
\end{align} 
Don't confuse the symbols, $u,v$ and $w$ are real numbers, whereas $3x^2+x+2,-x+1$ and $1$ are polynomials.

Comment: You re right!. Thank you.